# ActiveRecord update_attributes to ignore invalid keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a built in method similar to `update_attributes` that will ignore invalid keys in the hash passed in as parameter? If not, what's the best way to deal with the situation where you are sent a hash which may or may not include valid keys?

Comment: By "valid key", do you mean "a symbol that represents an existing attribute of the model (won't raise `undefined method`)" or "a `key => value` pair that will pass validations"?

Comment: "a symbol that represents an existing attribute of the model (won't raise undefined method)"

Comment: You should accept an answer if it fits your question @0xSina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything that accomplishes this out of the box in Rails. I'm also not aware of a simple way to determine in general what a model's "defined attributes" are—since a model may have overridden setters, virtual attributes, etc. Whenever I've needed this functionality, I've just explicitly defined a list of acceptable symbols in the class, something like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def defined_attributes
    [ :a, :b, :c ]
  end
end
```

...and then used that later in some kind of filtering step:

```
  attrs = { :a => 1, :z => 0 }
  foo.update_attributes(attrs.slice(*foo.defined_attributes))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is running obj.valid? and removing the invalid keys (the ones from obj.errors array) before calling update_attributes.

```
def update_valid_attributes(o)  
  o.errors.messages.each do {|k,msg| o.delete k} if !o.valid?
  o.update_attributes
end
```

You can also add this method to ActiveRecord::Base if you want it in all your persisted entities.

Comment: "Valid key": "a symbol that represents an existing attribute of the model (won't raise undefined method)" I think OxSina is looking for a way to delete params that are not attributes of the model. Am I right @OxSina ?

Comment: @OxSina In that case go with MrYoshi's solution.